# May I know the best way to test "Robot or Human" in .Net (In Web with C#.Net)

Tags: .net, validation

[image]

Hi Every One,

Happy new year. I have one question to ask this big Stack Over Flow community.
Could any one please suggest be the best way to perform **"Robot"** or "**Human"** test in .Net applications. Above **Image**, I copied from gmail while creating account(thanks to google).
I'm planning to perform similar validation before creating the account in my .Net web Application.  So, please suggest  the best approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a bazillion articles, code samples, and libraries on .NET and CAPTCHA.

Comment: Yep, it's called a CAPTCHA, but it's hard to find it if you don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recaptcha is one of the better/best services I am aware of that makes this really easy for you as a developer:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: Also see [reCAPTCHA for ASP.NET](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html).